# i want to generate two combo box dynamically ,and want to bind them together at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

for example: I generate two combo-boxes box1 and box2 dynamically(on run time with a add button click) and on the selected index change of box1, items in box2 should be changed ;data in both boxes is fetched from database.

```
      int cnt = 0;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.BusinessUltra1_2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlConnection conb = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.BusinessUltra1_2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.BusinessUltra1_2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.BusinessUltra1_2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.BusinessUltra1_2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cnt++;
        AddNewComboBox();
        AddNewComboBox1();
    }

    private void AddNewComboBox()
    {
        ComboBox myNewComboBox = new ComboBox();
        myNewComboBox.Name = "ComboBox1" + cnt.ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from company", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "company");
        myNewComboBox.DataSource = ds.Tables["company"];
        myNewComboBox.DisplayMember = ds.Tables["company"].Columns[0].ToString();
        myNewComboBox.ValueMember = ds.Tables["company"].Columns[0].ToString();
        //Program.counteritems = myNewComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        myNewComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(myNewComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myNewComboBox);

        con.Close();


    }



    private void AddNewComboBox1()
    {
       //string xyz = Program.counteritems;
        ComboBox myNewComboBox1 = new ComboBox();
        myNewComboBox1.Name = "ComboBox2" + cnt.ToString();
        conb.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from company", con);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        adp1.Fill(ds1, "company");
        myNewComboBox1.DataSource = ds1.Tables["company"];
        myNewComboBox1.DisplayMember = ds1.Tables["company"].Columns[1].ToString();
        myNewComboBox1.ValueMember = ds1.Tables["company"].Columns[1].ToString();
        //myNewComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender);

        myNewComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(myNewComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(myNewComboBox1);
        //changefunction();
        conb.Close();

    }
    void myNewComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var cbox1 = sender as ComboBox;
        if (cbox1 != null)
        {
            if (cbox1.Name == "ComboBox1" + cnt.ToString())
            {
                var cbox2 = flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(c => c.Name == "ComboBox2" + cnt.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                cbox2.SelectedValue = cbox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

                con2.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adfgtyu = new SqlDataAdapter("select *  from Cat_Comp_Item where (Category_Name='" + cbox1.SelectedText + "') ", con2);
                DataSet dsft = new DataSet();
                adfgtyu.Fill(dsft, "Cat_Comp_Item");
                cbox2.DataSource = dsft.Tables["Cat_Comp_Item"];
                cbox2.DisplayMember = dsft.Tables["Cat_Comp_Item"].Columns[1].ToString();

                con2.Close();
           }
        } 

         //string combochange1 = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myNewComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()))
        //{
        //    myNewComboBox1.SelectedValue = myNewComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        //}


     }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AddNewComboBox();
        AddNewComboBox1();
    }


    void myNewComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Press OK to select this ");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have ID column or primary key column in your company Table?

Comment: if combobox1 selection change then how you need to load the second combobox? you need to select the matching record or filter data in second cobobox?

Comment: i will briefly explain you

Comment: i will briefly explain you :-on the load event  i want that 2 combobox  should be created and both should pick data from  different columns of a same table ex combobox1 (column 1 - country) & combo box 2(column 2 - states) and now when someone changes the selection of combobox1 ..simultaneous values of combox2 should be seen

Comment: i also dont have any primary key, just two columns in the table  country and states

Comment: thanks damith but still the selectedindexchanged  of first combobox shows error when i applied your code.. the error is that combobox1 doesnot exist in current context

Comment: damith you can look at the updated code now please tell me what can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below

```
    private void myNewComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cbox1 = sender as ComboBox;
        if (cbox1 != null)
        {
            if (cbox1.Name == "ComboBox1")
            {
               var cbox2 = flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(c => c.Name == "ComboBox2").FirstOrDefault();
               cbox2.SelectedValue = cbox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
        } 
    }
```

To Do that you need to set `comboBox2.ValueMember` and `comboBox1.ValueMember` as same column in your company Table. select ID column or primary key column for that.

And also name your comboboxes as `ComboBox1` and `ComboBox2` when you create it like below

```
ComboBox myNewComboBox = new ComboBox();
myNewComboBox.Name = "ComboBox1";
```

And do the same for ComboBox2

Comment: damith the code you have suggested solves my purpose upto some extent but,,,,just please help me to refine it                                                   the problem is that when i am selecting something from combobox1 the combobox2 getting empty and the selectedindexchange of combobox2 is fired(i have a message in it and its being displayed)               i want that the selection in combobox2 should be changed accordingly(from database tables)

Comment: thanks damith i have worked it out your code also helped me ...i am posting the updated and working code for other people struggling with similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you should bind first combobox value and second combobox add just text(---select---) on add button and letter on first combobox index change bind second combobox

Comment: actually the problem is when i have already binded the second box on the load event ,i am unable to bind it again on the selected event change of the first box.

Comment: try   comboBox.SelectedValue = "value"; or

Comment: comboBox.SelectedItem = item;

Comment: thanks amol i have updated the code now could you please tell me what can be done